# Is there a way to assert a list of strings to the output of a command in groovy?

Tags: groovy

Ran a command and stored the output like so in groovy

```
def task = ['bash', '-c', runImpactBuild].execute()
task.waitFor()
def outputString = task.in.text
```

now I'm trying to pass in a list of strings that I expect to see in the output of the command

```
 def list = ['test', 'tests'];
 assert outputString.contains(list)
```

but I'm seeing this error when running the script.

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.contains() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[test, tests]]
Possible solutions: contains(java.lang.CharSequence), contains(java.lang.CharSequence), toString(), toString(), toString(), notify()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.contains() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[test, tests]]
Possible solutions: contains(java.lang.CharSequence), contains(java.lang.CharSequence), toString(), toString(), toString(), notify()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assert list.count{ i-> outputString.contains(i) } == list.size()
```

Comment: `["a", "c"].every{ "a z c".contains it }`